# How to update the Shopify CLI on Node.js?

Tags: command-line-interface, shopify, upgrade

I'm trying to update my Shopify CLI to its latest version but when I run `npm run shopify upgrade` Node.js gives me this error...

[image]

Do you know what it means?

Answer (score 1):

The confusions seems to be that the 2.xx Shopify CLI is for themes only and runs via the terminal fine and what I understand are core ruby calls. 3.0 is trying to run via NPM purely so in your package.json you would need :

```html
 "scripts": {
    "shopify": "shopify",
    "build": "shopify app build",
    "dev": "shopify app dev",
    "push": "shopify app push",
    "scaffold": "shopify app scaffold",
    "deploy": "shopify app deploy",
    "info": "shopify app info"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@shopify/app": "3.10.1",
    "@shopify/cli": "3.10.1"
  },
```

in order to run what youve mentioned

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Darren Mc, in the end I found that the problem was I was  trying to update the cli via npm and not via Ruby. The right command is `gem update shopify-cli`